# No prompt on boot with full disk encryption enabled

Tags: linux-mint, encryption

I am able to successfully authenticate by typing in the encryption password (and hitting return), but nothing is displayed on the screen to prompt me for this information. I tend to just "wait enough time" before attempting to type in my password.

A coworker said he observed the same behavior, but hitting the ESC key while the system was waiting for the password input would force it to draw the prompt.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're using for encryption, what hardware (specifically GPU) you're using and what distro/kernel you're running?

Comment: @DavidKing, During install of Linux Mint it asks if you would like to enable FDE, so I am not sure of any further details. The GPU in my laptop is a AMD Radeon HD 9790M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess would be that for some reason the splash screen is hiding or blocking the passphrase prompt. You can check whether this is the case by switching off the splash screen. To do so, we must make changes to the configuration of the bootloader which in mint should be grub (GRand Unified Bootloader):

- Start a terminal (if you don't know how, one foolproof way is to press <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gnome-terminal`
- Before you make changes to the config file, create a backup you can revert to if anything goes wrong:

```bash
$ sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bkp
```

- now you can edit the grub configuration file (`nano` is a simple and easy to use editor, replace it with your own pick if you prefer):

```bash
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

- Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, look for the `splash` option within the double quotes and delete it.
- save the file and exit the editor - to do this in in `nano`, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> (`nano` will ask whether you want to save changes before exiting)
- now you have made changes to the system-wide default configuration for grub. However, these need to be translated to grubs own config file format to actually take effect. To do so, enter:

```bash
$ sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot the system. There should be no graphical splash screen anymore, instead some text based boot messages among which you should now be able to see the passphrase prompt when you get to it.

(To return to the previous state, you can restore the backup of the configuration file by opening a terminal again, entering `sudo mv /etc/default/grub.bkp /etc/default/grub` and then `sudo update-grub`.)

**Note:** If this works, it isn't actually so much a solution as a workaround, since we didn't actually track down the problem and solve it. I haven't worked on either Mint or Ubuntu for quite a while but I remember that there were sometimes problems with missing passphrase prompts on client machines and the quickest (though roughest) remedy was to switch off splash altogether. If my assumption is right and the problem is related to the splash screen, then the actual cause can be anything from wrong options to bugs. But for more indepth troubleshooting, you would need to give more detailed information about your system and propably also someone who has a machine running Mint themselves.

Comment: @sherrellbc : did you get to try this out? If it doesn't help, maybe you can send the results of `lsb_release -a` and `lspci -k | sed -n '/VGA/,/Kernel driver/p'`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That seemed to fix it!